# package org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul does not exist

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jhipster

I am moving some test code from an older jHipster project to a new one. The old project uses the org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul library, specifically org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-netflix-core:1.3.0.RELEASE .

I put the below in my new project's pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-zuul</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

However, it seems to be pulling in org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:2.2.5.RELEASE. This release does not contain zuul in it however, as this code fails import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.

Does anyone know a fix or workaround?

Old library. 
org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-netflix-core:1.3.0.RELEASE

My new project is using 
org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:2.2.5.RELEASE

UPDATE: 
Sorry I updated my question - my pom file already has this code. But it is very weird to me that even though I put to 1.3.0, I can see in my maven dependencies that it's pulling in 2.2.5. Also when I right click my project, I see maven - reimport and maven - generate sources etc.. I don't see a update project. And clicking both of those doesn't seem to downgrade it to 1.3.0

Comment: Why would you believe that `spring-boot` would include `spring-cloud-netflix-core` by default? Seems you should add `org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-zuul:2.2.2.RELEASE`

Comment: I believe JHipster moved to Spring Cloud gateway https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/pull/11223 away from Zuul

Comment: JHipster still supports Zuul and we also support Spring Cloud Gateway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you update your pom.xml file your problem would solve.
In your pom.xml file you'll see dependencies tag you need to add the library you want and then right click your project and say maven -> update project

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-netflix-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.0.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add following dependency to your pom.xml

```
 <dependency>

 <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>    
 
 <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-zuul</artifactId>    
 
 <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>    
 </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading spring-boot to >= 2.5 requires some extra configuration in order for Zuul to keep working, see:

https://gist.github.com/aldobongio/6a22f49863c7a777612f7887bbb8fd1d